# GUI program that uses a recursive function - Need help finding an error. (JAVA)

Tags: java, swing, recursion

I need help finding an error in my program.
The assignment was:
Recursive Multiplication.

Write a GUI program that uses a recursive function. The user will enter a number in a textfield and when a button is clicked, the button will call a function called recursive.

This function accepts two arguments into the parameters x and y. The function should return the value of x times y. Remember, multiplication can be performed as repeated addition as follows: 7 * 4 = 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 or 7 * 4 = 7 + 7 + 7 + 7

Test your program for negative numbers.

Here is my program:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;        
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Recursion extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private JLabel xLabel;           // To reference a label
private JLabel yLabel;           // To reference a label
private JTextField xTextField;   // To reference a text field
private JTextField yTextField;   // To reference a text field 
private JTextField resultField;  // To reference a text field  
private JButton calcButton;      // To reference a calculate button  
private int total = 0; 

public Recursion() {

    // Set the title bar text.
    setTitle("Multiplication"); 

    // Specify an action for the close button.
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    // Add a FlowLayout manager to the content pane.
    setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 

    // Set the size of the window.
    setSize(450, 120); 

    xLabel = new JLabel("Enter x");        
    add(xLabel);        
    xTextField = new JTextField("0", 8);        
    add(xTextField);        
    yLabel = new JLabel("Enter y");        
    add(yLabel);        
    yTextField = new JTextField("0", 8);        
    add(yTextField);        

    // Create a read-only text field for the result.
    resultField = new JTextField("0", 8);        
    resultField.setEditable(false);        
    add(resultField);  

    // Create a button with the caption "Calculate".
    calcButton = new JButton("Calculate");        
    add(calcButton);        
    calcButton.addActionListener(this);        

    // Display the window.   
    setVisible(true);    
}    

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) 
{        
    int x = Integer.parseInt(xLabel.getText());        
    int y = Integer.parseInt(yLabel.getText());        
    total = Multiply(x,y);       
    resultField.setText(" " + total);    
}   

public int Multiply(int x,int y){        
    if(y==1)            
        return x;        
    else
    {            
        return x + Multiply(x, y-1);        
    }    
}
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    Recursion app = new Recursion();
}
}
```

The compiler is showing this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Enter x"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)....................
...............................
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are trying to read input from your label rather than text field. SO you are trying to convert "Enter x" to int as a result....

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(xLabel.getText());` are you sure you want to read text from label? Isn't input which user provided placed in textField elements?

Comment: Thank you guys, I wasn't careful.